# How can you send multiple requests with requests.post?

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to send multiple requests to a website using `requests.post`. How can I do this? Do I have to use `range()` or should I use something else?

Here is my source code:

```py
requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False, data={
    '{usernameInput}': username,
    '{passwordInput}': password
})
```

Comment: Each call to `requests.post` represents one HTTP exchange, out and back.  Do you want to send N identical requests?  (If so, why?)  Or do you want to send N different requests?

Comment: Please refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752973/python-how-can-i-send-multiple-http-requests-at-the-same-time-like-fork).